# How to reach the item from a group in an ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, navigation-drawer, expandablelistadapter

I have an OnGroupClick-method to see if a specific Group in the ExpandableListView is a group. The model of the groups has  a list of ChildItems, when this is null, the ExpandableListView must not try to expand, but just execute code specific for that GroupItem.

I have this code that works:

```
mDrawerList.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
        if (groupPosition == 0 || groupPosition == 3) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Start clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }
});
```

What I tried is the following code:

```
mDrawerList.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
        JPPNavDrawerAdapter2 adapter = (JPPNavDrawerAdapter2) parent.getAdapter();
        JPPNavDrawerAdapter2.GroupItem item = (JPPNavDrawerAdapter2.GroupItem) adapter.getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (item.getChildren() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Start clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }
});
```

When I run this, my app crashes when I try to click on an item. What is wrong with this code? And how can I solve this?

Comment: can u post ur logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getAdapter()` method will not return you the instance of adapter you have defined using `setAdapter()`. You  must use `getExpandableListAdapter()` instead. The documentation [clearly states this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#getAdapter()).